# Model reservation with 2 selects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

Hi I am developing a car park reservation system, I have an array of objects that look like this

```
    $scope.availability = [
        {
            date: "Mon, 20 June 2014",
            spaces: [
                1,
                ...,
                X
            ]
        },
        {
            date: "Mon, 21 June 2014",
            spaces: [
                1,
                ...,
                X
            ]
        },
        {
            date: "Mon, 22 June 2014",
            spaces: [
                1,
                ...,
                X
            ]
        },
        {
            date: "Mon, 23 June 2014",
            spaces: [
                1,
                ...,
                X
            ]
        }
    ];
```

The user can select to reserve upto 10 spaces (these can be hard coded) on multiple dates.

I have a similar array in which to save selected dates and number of spaces called

```
$scope.selectedDates = [
    {
        date: null,
        spaces: null
    }
]
```

I want to be able to have the user populate data and spaces based on what they select. selectedDates has an extra object added to it, when ever a user clicks a button (this works)
what is the best way to go about doing this with angular?

Comment: can you post a plunkr with a quick mockup of your code so that we can see the intended use?

Comment: i'll try and whack up a jsfiddle, but it doesnt even come close to working atm

Comment: That's fine. Comment the code with current behavior and expected behavior.